# Woocommerce clear cart after payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having trouble clearing my cart after payment but I'm using Woocommerce.
I used codes and plugin from an older site (before the major update in the beginning of the year) and that doesn't seem to work now on the new updated site.

This is the functions.php

```
// check for clear-cart get param to clear the cart
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['clear-cart'] ) ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
```

In the thankyou.php that appears after succesfull payment this code is in there.

```
<!-- clear cart after successfull payment -->

jQuery(function($) {
    $.post("http://ihavetakenoutmydomain.org?clear-cart",{},function(response){
            var NewCart = $(response).find('#header-cart-inner');
            $('#header-cart').html(NewCart);

            var NewCartItems = $(response).find('.cart-items-inner');
            $('.cart-items').html(NewCartItems);
        });
    });
```

I'm using the same theme as in the older version so the header-cart-inner and header-cart are the same.

But for some reason this doesn't work with the updated Wordpress and Woocommerce.
Does anyone know what the problem might be or have another solution for clearing the cart after succesfull payment? The thankyou page should only appear after successfull payment.

I forgot one thing
If I load the link "xxx://ihavetakenoutmydomain.org?clear-cart" on my browser the cart empties. So I guess the problem would be how to activate the link on the thankyou page without redirecting away from the thankyou page.
Best regards

Comment: I've found out that this script works in internet explorer so it clears the cart after successfull payment but I'm using Chrome and it seems not to work in there.

Comment: Are you using a current version of WooCommerce? Because the cart clears automatically after payment is completed.